# How to get asp.net mvc controller to talk with google maps api - Adding markers dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

I am working with the Google Maps API.  I have the map displaying on my page, I can add markers to it manually, everything is working correctly.

Now I need to build a marker list from mvc and figure out how to pass it back to the map through asp.net MVC.  Everything I need for the marker list is contained in the dtDealer_List shown below.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dtDealer_List.Rows)
      {
          dealer_list dl = new dealer_list();
          dl.address = row["address"].ToString();
          .......
          lstDealer_List.Add(dl);
      }
```

I'm not sure on how to pass this list back to the javascript function.

```
function init_map(map_canvas_id, lat, lng, zoomLevel) {
            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

            var options = {
                zoom: zoomLevel,
                center: myLatLng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
            };

            var map_canvas = document.getElementById(map_canvas_id);

            var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, options);
        }
```

Do I need to pull out the dtDealer_List into a ajax call or something?

Comment: do you have the `dtDealer_List` ready on page load?  If so you can just use it as the model or send it in the ViewBag.  If not, you'll need to use AJAX

Comment: dtDealer_List is passed through to the page as the model.  How can I use that to populate javascript/jQuery function call? @Jonesy

Comment: @Jonesy I'll play around with it found a couple of posts on passing model to javascript.  Thanks for the idea.

Comment: I added a solution - took me a bit to remember razor/javascript syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a small script at the top of your page to set up a javascript array from your list:

```
@model List<string>

<script>
    var addresses = [];
    @foreach (var address in Model)
    {
        <text>addresses.push('@address')</text>
    }
    console.log(addresses);
</script>
```

then you should be able to access the global `addresses` array where you need

Comment: I will play around with that and report back in a little bit, thank you.